# Using other files along with EMR streaming step?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce

I currently have a hadoop command that I would like to copy using the AWS SDK.

The command I'm currently using

```
hadoop jar /home/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar -input /no_dups -output /sorted -mapper mapper.py -reducer reducer.py -file mapper.py reducer.py other_file1.py other_file2.py
```

As far as I can see, the `StreamingStep` class doesn't provide a way to let Hadoop know that other files will be needed, along with the mapper and reducer.

Is this functionality available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by passing the `-file` option to `HadoopJarStepConfig` with a list of the files I needed.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241520/adding-extra-arguements-to-hadoopjarstepconfig-fails/16275484#16275484)